Is Pat Akum applicable nowadays
The Mishnah in Avodah Zarah 2:6 discusses the prohibition of bread baked by a gentile, also known as Pat Akum. My question is whether nowadays, when the Halacha LeMaaseh appears to permit that, whether the original Gezeirah has been completely revoked or no, there are just a lot of Heterim limiting its scope?

There's a chapter in Shulchan Arukh about its laws (YD 112). Does that answer your question?

Pas Akum is always forbidden. What is permissible according to many is Pas Palter, baked goods made by non Jewish Professional Baker for Commercial purposes.

If there are no local bakers than some say even Pas Akum could be permitted https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%97
